# Error deploying firebase functions after initialising gts

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

## Intention:

I want to use Google's TypeScript style guide [gts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gts) in my Firebase Functions project.

## Expected Result:

The command `firebase deploy --only functions` should still successfully deploy my functions without errors after running `npx gts init`.

## Actual Result:

Deployment of my functions fails even after fixing numerous obvious issues.

## Steps to reproduce:

1. Initialise the firebase functions project by running `firebase init functions` in an empty folder.
2. Add relevant functions code to the `src/` directory.
3. Run the `"deploy"` script, or run `firebase deploy --only functions` from a terminal.

   - Result: functions deploy without any issues.
4. Run `npx gts init` in the `functions/` directory to initialise gts.
5. Run the `"deploy"` script, or run `firebase deploy --only functions` from a terminal.

   - Result: deployment fails:

     - Error: There was an error reading functions\package.json:
       functions\lib\index.js does not exist, can't deploy Cloud Functions
6. Fix directory mismatch.

   - Result: deployment still fails with same error.
7. Fix location of `"main"`.

   - Result: deployment fails:

     - Error: npm.cmd: not found.
8. Fix `npm.cmd: not found` by removing `.cmd` from scripts.

   - Result: deployment fails:

     - Error: `tsc: not found`

Below I've listed the project structure and contents of relevant project files at some of the key stages from the above list.
My apologies if it seems verbose, but I thought it best to try and cover most of the potentially relevant info.

#### After initialising the Firebase functions project, but before initializing gts:

Project has standard Firebase Functions structure.

```bash
my-project
 +- functions/     # Directory containing all your functions code
      |
      +- lib/
      |   |
      |   +- index.js  # Built/transpiled JavaScript code
      |   |
      |   +- index.js.map # Source map for debugging
      |
      +- src/     # Directory containing TypeScript source
      |   |
      |   +- index.ts  # main source file for your Cloud Functions code
      |
      +- .eslintrc.js # Optional file if you enabled ESLint
      |
      +- package.json  # npm package file describing your Cloud Functions code
      |
      +- tsconfig.dev.json # Optional file that references .eslintrc.js
      |
      +- tsconfig.json
```

##### .eslintrc.js

```js
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    es6: true,
    node: true,
  },
  extends: [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:import/errors",
    "plugin:import/warnings",
    "plugin:import/typescript",
    "google",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
  ],
  parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  parserOptions: {
    project: ["tsconfig.json", "tsconfig.dev.json"],
    sourceType: "module",
  },
  ignorePatterns: [
    "/lib/**/*", // Ignore built files.
  ],
  plugins: [
    "@typescript-eslint",
    "import",
  ],
  rules: {
    "quotes": ["error", "double"],
    "import/no-unresolved": 0,
    "indent": ["error", 2],
  },
};
```

##### package.json

```json
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.ts .",
    "build": "tsc",
    "build:watch": "tsc --watch",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "16"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^11.5.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^4.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.12.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.12.0",
    "eslint": "^8.9.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.4",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^3.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

##### tsconfig.dev.json

```json
{
  "include": [
    ".eslintrc.js"
  ]
}
```

##### tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2017"
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

In the above project state the `"deploy"` script completes successfully. The functions are deployed without any errors.

### After initializing gts:

Project structure.

```bash
my-project
 +- functions/     # Directory containing all your functions code
      |
      +- lib/
      |   |
      |   +- index.js  # Built/transpiled JavaScript code
      |   |
      |   +- index.js.map # Source map for debugging
      |
      +- src/     # Directory containing TypeScript source
      |   |
      |   +- index.ts  # main source file for your Cloud Functions code
      |
      +- .editorconfig
      |
      +- .eslintignore
      |
      +- .eslintrc.js # Optional file if you enabled ESLint
      |
      +- .eslintrc.json
      |
      +- .prettierrc.js
      |
      +- package.json  # npm package file describing your Cloud Functions code
      |
      +- tsconfig.dev.json # Optional file that references .eslintrc.js
      |
      +- tsconfig.json
```

##### .editorconfig

```bash
root = true

[*]
indent_style = space
indent_size = 2
end_of_line = lf
charset = utf-8
insert_final_newline = true
```

##### .eslintignore

```bash
build/
```

##### .eslintrc.js

*No change.*

##### .eslintrc.json

```
{
  "extends": "./node_modules/gts/"
}
```

##### .prettierrc.js

```js
module.exports = {
  ...require('gts/.prettierrc.json')
}
```

##### package.json

```json
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "gts lint",
    "build": "tsc",
    "build:watch": "tsc --watch",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log",
    "clean": "gts clean",
    "compile": "tsc",
    "fix": "gts fix",
    "prepare": "npm.cmd run compile",
    "pretest": "npm.cmd run compile",
    "posttest": "npm.cmd run lint"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "16"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^11.5.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^4.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.12.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.12.0",
    "eslint": "^8.9.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.4",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^3.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.7.0",
    "gts": "^3.1.1",
    "@types/node": "^14.11.2"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

##### tsconfig.dev.json

*No change.*

##### tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "extends": "./node_modules/gts/tsconfig-google.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": ".",
    "outDir": "build"
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "test/**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

In the above project state the `"deploy"` script fails with the error:

```bash
Error: There was an error reading functions\package.json:

 functions\lib\index.js does not exist, can't deploy Cloud Functions
```

This error is because by default Firebase functions sets the `"outDir"` in `tsconfig.json` to `"lib"`, but initialising gts changes the `"outDir"` to `"build"`.
I'm not sure how I would go about changing the `"deploy"` script to expect the `"outDir"` to be `"build"`, so I instead reverted the `"outDir"` to be `"lib"`.

### After reverting to `"outDir": "lib"` in `tsconfig.json`:

##### tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "extends": "./node_modules/gts/tsconfig-google.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": ".",
    "outDir": "lib"
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "test/**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

In this project state the `"deploy"` script again fails with the error:

```bash
Error: There was an error reading functions\package.json:

 functions\lib\index.js does not exist, can't deploy Cloud Functions
```

This time the error is because `index.js` gets built to the directory `functions\lib\src\` not `functions\lib\`.
I fixed this issue by changing `"main": "lib/index.js"` in `package.json` to `"main": "lib/src/index.js"`.

### After setting `"main": "lib/src/index.js"` in `package.json`:

##### package.json

```json
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "gts lint",
    "build": "tsc",
    "build:watch": "tsc --watch",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log",
    "clean": "gts clean",
    "compile": "tsc",
    "fix": "gts fix",
    "prepare": "npm.cmd run compile",
    "pretest": "npm.cmd run compile",
    "posttest": "npm.cmd run lint"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "16"
  },
  "main": "lib/src/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^11.5.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^4.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.12.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.12.0",
    "eslint": "^8.9.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.4",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^3.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.7.0",
    "gts": "^3.1.1",
    "@types/node": "^14.11.2"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

In this project state the `"deploy"` script fails as shown below:

```bash
i  deploying functions
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint

> lint
> gts lint

version: 16

Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run build

> build
> tsc

+  functions: Finished running predeploy script.
i  functions: preparing codebase default for deployment
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  artifactregistry: ensuring required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled...
+  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
+  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
+  artifactregistry: required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged D:\Projects\my-project\functions (127.84 KB) for uploading
i  functions: ensuring required API identitytoolkit.googleapis.com is enabled...
+  functions: required API identitytoolkit.googleapis.com is enabled
+  functions: functions folder uploaded successfully
i  functions: updating Node.js 16 function userBeforeCreate(us-central1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 16 function userOnCreate(us-central1)...
Build failed: > prepare
> npm.cmd run compile

sh: 1: npm.cmd: not found
npm ERR! code 127
npm ERR! path /workspace
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c -- npm.cmd run compile

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /www-data-home/.npm/_logs/2023-05-05T09_23_49_048Z-debug-0.log; Error ID: beaf8772
Build failed: > prepare
> npm.cmd run compile

sh: 1: npm.cmd: not found
npm ERR! code 127
npm ERR! path /workspace
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c -- npm.cmd run compile

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /www-data-home/.npm/_logs/2023-05-05T09_24_40_038Z-debug-0.log; Error ID: beaf8772

Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
        userBeforeCreate(us-central1)
        userOnCreate(us-central1)
i  functions: cleaning up build files...
Error: There was an error deploying functions:
- Error Failed to update function userBeforeCreate in region us-central1
- Error Failed to update function userOnCreate in region us-central1

Process finished with exit code 2
```

And here's one of the Google Cloud logs mentioned (they're both essentially identical)[Note: ids etc have been xxxxx hidden]:

```json
{
  "protoPayload": {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog",
    "status": {
      "code": 3,
      "message": "Build failed: > prepare\n> npm.cmd run compile\n\nsh: 1: npm.cmd: not found\nnpm ERR! code 127\nnpm ERR! path /workspace\nnpm ERR! command failed\nnpm ERR! command sh -c -- npm.cmd run compile\n\nnpm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:\nnpm ERR!     /www-data-home/.npm/_logs/2023-05-05T09_10_41_708Z-debug-0.log; Error ID: beaf8772"
    },
    "authenticationInfo": {},
    "serviceName": "cloudfunctions.googleapis.com",
    "methodName": "google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.UpdateFunction",
    "resourceName": "projects/my-project/locations/us-central1/functions/userBeforeCreate"
  },
  "insertId": "xxxxx",
  "resource": {
    "type": "cloud_function",
    "labels": {
      "region": "us-central1",
      "function_name": "userBeforeCreate",
      "project_id": "my-project"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2023-05-05T09:10:59.793425Z",
  "severity": "ERROR",
  "logName": "projects/my-project/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity",
  "operation": {
    "id": "operations/xxxxx",
    "producer": "cloudfunctions.googleapis.com",
    "last": true
  },
  "receiveTimestamp": "2023-05-05T09:11:00.085118556Z"
}
```

To address the `npm.cmd: not found` issue, I then tried removing `.cmd` from the `"prepare"`, `"pretest"` & `"posttest"` scripts in `package.json`.

### After removing `.cmd` from the `"prepare"`, `"pretest"` & `"posttest"` scripts:

##### package.json

```json
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "gts lint",
    "build": "tsc",
    "build:watch": "tsc --watch",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log",
    "clean": "gts clean",
    "compile": "tsc",
    "fix": "gts fix",
    "prepare": "npm run compile",
    "pretest": "npm run compile",
    "posttest": "npm run lint"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "16"
  },
  "main": "lib/src/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^11.5.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^4.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.12.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.12.0",
    "eslint": "^8.9.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.4",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^3.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.7.0",
    "gts": "^3.1.1",
    "@types/node": "^14.11.2"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

In this project state the `"deploy"` script fails as shown below:

```bash
i  deploying functions
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint

> lint
> gts lint

version: 16

Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run build

> build
> tsc

+  functions: Finished running predeploy script.
i  functions: preparing codebase default for deployment
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  artifactregistry: ensuring required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled...
+  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
+  artifactregistry: required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled
+  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged D:\Projects\my-project\functions (127.96 KB) for uploading
i  functions: ensuring required API identitytoolkit.googleapis.com is enabled...
+  functions: required API identitytoolkit.googleapis.com is enabled
+  functions: functions folder uploaded successfully
i  functions: updating Node.js 16 function userBeforeCreate(us-central1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 16 function userOnCreate(us-central1)...
Build failed: > prepare
> npm run compile


> compile
> tsc

sh: 1: tsc: not found
npm ERR! code 127
npm ERR! path /workspace
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c -- npm run compile

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /www-data-home/.npm/_logs/2023-05-05T10_46_49_310Z-debug-0.log; Error ID: beaf8772
Build failed: > prepare
> npm run compile


> compile
> tsc

sh: 1: tsc: not found
npm ERR! code 127
npm ERR! path /workspace
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c -- npm run compile

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /www-data-home/.npm/_logs/2023-05-05T10_47_18_266Z-debug-0.log; Error ID: beaf8772

Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
        userBeforeCreate(us-central1)
        userOnCreate(us-central1)
i  functions: cleaning up build files...
Error: There was an error deploying functions:
- Error Failed to update function userBeforeCreate in region us-central1
- Error Failed to update function userOnCreate in region us-central1

Process finished with exit code 2
```

I don't know how to fix the issue from here, so any assistance would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've manage to replicate your issue.
Here are the steps on what I did:

1. Created a project in a clear folder named `"FirebaseGTS"` using the code you provided `"firebase init functions"`
2. Fill the necessary information needed. E.g (existing project, Project ID)

Then

Language: `TypeScript`

Do you want to use ESLint to catch probable bugs and enforce style ? : `"NO"`

It will automatically create the following:

```
Wrote functions/package.json
Wrote functions/tsconfig.json
Wrote functions/src/index.ts
Wrote functions/.gitignore
```

Next

Install dependencies with npm now ? : `YES` this adds all the packages needed.

3. I used `firebase deploy --only functions`

Result: Deployed without any issues.

4. Now here i installed the `npx gts init` inside the function folder as  you mentioned.

Package.json does not exist. Generate ? : `YES`

"Auto generation"

```
Writes package.json
Writes ./tsconfig.json
Writes ./.eslintrc.json
Writes ./.eslintignore
Writes ./.prettierrc.js
Writes ./.editorconfig
```

Result: added packages, and audited packages needed.

**Note**: Dont Overwrite the devDependency since you have the lastest which is v4.9.0 rather than v4.7.0

5. Inside the function folder, i just did `firebase deploy --only functions`

Result: Deploy Complete!

Comment: If you uncomment the `helloWorld` function so you actually have something to deploy, it still fails as before after initializing gts.